# Can I use google colab light color scheme in Jetbrains IDEs

Tags: google-colaboratory, jetbrains-ide

I found that light color scheme in `google colab`, for me, are much better than any present in `JetBrains` by default. Can I install it in the `JetBrains`?

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot use the Google Colab light color scheme in Jetbrains IDEs. Each IDE has its own set of color schemes and themes, and they are not interchangeable between different IDEs. However, you may be able to find a similar light color scheme in the Jetbrains IDEs that suits your preferences.